# How do I determine $a, b $ for which $\lim\frac{\sqrt{x²+ax}+b}{x²-1}=\frac{1}{2}$ when $x$ go to $-1$does satisfied?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

How do i determine $a$ and $b$ for which :
$$\lim_{x \to -1}\frac{\sqrt{x²+ax}+b}{x²-1}=\frac{1}{2}$$ does satisfied ?

Attempt : I have used l'hopitale rule and substitution i have got $a=0$ and $b=1$ or $-1$ , I would like to know if what i got is true or there are others values of $a$ and $b$ ?

Thank you for any help .

Answer (score 1):

Since the denominator goes to $0$ as $x\to -1$, the numerator also has to go $0$. So, $\sqrt{(-1)^2+a\cdot (-1)}+b=0,$ i.e. $b=-\sqrt{1-a}$.

So, we have
$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to -1}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+ax}-\sqrt{1-a}}{x^2-1}&=\lim_{x\to -1}\frac{(x^2+ax)-(1-a)}{x^2-1}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+ax}+\sqrt{1-a}}\\&=\lim_{x\to -1}\frac{(x+1)(x-1+a)}{(x-1)(x+1)}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+ax}+\sqrt{1-a}}\\&=\lim_{x\to -1}\frac{x-1+a}{x-1}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+ax}+\sqrt{1-a}}\\&=\frac{-2+a}{-2}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-a}+\sqrt{1-a}}\end{align}$$

Now, solving
$$\frac{-2+a}{-2}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-a}+\sqrt{1-a}}=\frac 12$$
gives $a=0$. So, $b=-1$.

Comment: By l'hopitale also b=1 is a solution

Comment: @zeraouliarafik L'Hôpital's Rule requires that the quotient is an indeterminate form like $0/0$. You can't use it on things you can't put in this form, or you'd get nonsense like $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x-1}{x}"="1$.

Comment: 0/0 means that denominator divise numenator and if you say that nominator must be go to 0 at x=-1 so you have 0/0

Comment: @zeraouliarafik: We have to have $b=-\sqrt{1-a}$. So, $b$ has to be at least non-positive.

Comment: I meant in your claim you seek for 0/0 which l'hopitale rule necessite this to be applicable

Comment: @zeraouliarafik: Please notice that you cannot use l'hopital **unless** you have $\sqrt{(-1)^2+a\cdot (-1)}+b=0$.

Answer (score 0):

In order that the limit exist, the numerator must also be zero at $x=-1$. Hence $\sqrt{1-a}+b=0$. The square root is positive, so $b$ must be negative. Now we have to find $a$ so that the limit is $1/2$, which we can do as follows:
$$ \sqrt{x^2+ax}-\sqrt{1-a} = \frac{x^2+ax-1+a}{\sqrt{x^2+ax}+\sqrt{1-a}} = \frac{(x+1)(x+a-1)}{\sqrt{x^2+ax}+\sqrt{1-a}}. $$
Now going back to the original fraction,
$$ \frac{\sqrt{x^2+ax}-\sqrt{1-a}}{(x+1)(x-1)} = \frac{(x+1)(x+a-1)}{(x+1)(x-1)(\sqrt{x^2+ax}+\sqrt{1-a})} = \frac{x+a-1}{(x-1)(\sqrt{x^2+ax}+\sqrt{1-a})}, $$
and setting $x=-1$ gives
$$ \frac{a-2}{(-2)(2\sqrt{1-a})} = \frac{1}{2}, $$
which simplifies to $2-a=2\sqrt{1-a}$, so $(2-a)^2=4-4a$, of which the only solution is $a=0$.

Comment: what about the value  of  b ?

Comment: That's what I address in the first line.